# Regular Expression in Python - about a Specific Case

Tags: python, regex

here is a minimal test case -

```
>>>import re  
>>>re.findall('(\w+\n?) ([^(!END)]+) (!END\n?)',"!MDCNTL\n  !GENERIC LUNIT=7.9406324338 LONGRANGE=F TRACE=F SCALE=1.0 !END\n  !RDYN DT=5. FRIC=0.001 NSTEP=20000 !END\n  !LATTICE t= 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 !END\n !END")  
[('LATTICE', 't= 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0', '!END\n')]
```

Let me explain a bit the markup which is pretty similar to xml.
 1. The `!TAG` and `!END` correspond to `<tag>` and `</tag>` in xml
 2. Key value pairs are `key=value`
 3. Spaces are allowed in values

The regular expression is supposed to pick out the lowest level tags, or leaves. I do not understand why for this specific example returns only one of the leaves. Other similar examples i constructed give epected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = "!MDCNTL\n  !GENERIC .... "
>>> re.findall(r'(!(?!END)\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(!END)', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
[('!MDCNTL', '!GENERIC LUNIT=7.9406324338 LONGRANGE=F TRACE=F SCALE=1.0', '!END'),
 ('!RDYN', 'DT=5. FRIC=0.001 NSTEP=20000', '!END'),
 ('!LATTICE', 't= 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0', '!END')]
```

Used `re.DOTALL` flag to make `.` also match newline.

### Why does the regular expression in the question not work?

`[^(!END)]` matches a character that is not in `(`, `!`, `E`, `N`, `D`, `)`. (`[^.....]`: negative set of characters)

There's `E`/`N` in attributes of `GENERIC` tag, `RDYN` tag; these prevent match.

```
!GENERIC LUNIT=7.9406324338 LONGRANGE=F TRACE=F SCALE=1.0 !END
           ^                  ^   ^ ^       ^       ^
!RDYN DT=5. FRIC=0.001 NSTEP=20000 !END
                       ^  ^
```

Comment: I think you should explain what does `flags=re.DOTALL`

Comment: @akaRem, added an explanation. Thank you  for comment.